# Improving WebMail performance MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, webmail

I'm using the MVC helper WebMail to send emails.  However the speed of it seems to be of concern.  Especially when I have to send more than 1 email at the same time.  I tried using a thread, but that didn't work since the Webmail object was null.  How do I speed this up?  Any ideas appreciated.

Forgot to mention, this is during testing and I'm using localhost and gmail!  Not sure if that is causing the issue.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want performance, don't use the WebMail helper. Use the classes in the System.Net namespace.

This allows you to open a new thread and send the email out-of-band from the web request.

We use Google Apps mail (gmail) in the cloud, opening a new thread, and sending the email from there, using the System.Net types (not WebMail). It works pretty well, as we can respond to the user without having to wait for the email to be sent.

Be careful about using Google Apps / gmail though, especially in development. We had one of our accounts disabled by google because of this. During development, you should use your local ISP, or better yet, use SpecifiedPickupDirectory, as it works better when unit testing email receipt.

Comment: Thank you for that detailed answer @olivehour. I will be testing and possibly updating my code soon!